# How to Open New Window in c# without losing xml layout

Tags: c#, xaml, new-window

I have a c# project already working a main Window but when I created a New Window and use

```
Views.Form Form = new Views.Form();
Form.ShowDialog();
```

The page doe's open but it not showing the xml I deseigned and I think that the problem is in namespaces and derectories but havin hard time troubleshooting the proble so this is my solution explorer

```
   Properities
   References
   Model
     Acteur.cs
     Tache.cs
   ViewModels
     ActeurViewModel.cs
     TacheViewModel.cs
   Views
     Form.xaml
     MainWindow.xaml
   App.xaml
   Model.edmx
```

and this is the Form Window code :

## .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Form.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Form : Window
    {
        public Form()
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

## .xaml file

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Form"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Form" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Background="#FF142683">
        <Label  Name="Test" Content="this is a test" FontSize="43"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## the MainWindow Calling

```
private void AddButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Views.Form Form = new Views.Form();
            Form.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you delete the method "**InitializeComponent**();" in the constructor?

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

This method is created automatically by vs, and it will initialize those controls that you used in the XAML.cs.

Since you have deleted that method, that's the reason why you can not see your controls.

Just try to create a new window and you will find that method that I mentioned.

Comment: I Deleted it because it was returning the error **The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: maybe some other compiling errors cause the misinformation, you have to fix the error in the other place first and then the error of "InitializeComponent" will go away.

Comment: @Oscar that error often happens if you change a namespace after adding a window. You have nothing in your new window, just delete it and start a new one.